# Updating ProgressBar through thread in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, runnable

I am working on a Java project that makes use of JavaFX's ProgressBar. From what I found on StackOverflow, usually a thread needs to be added, or the program needs to implement Runnable, in order to update the ProgressBar's value dynamically, say when program is running in for loop.

However, looking at java doc and answers in stackoverflow, I am still not sure how, or what is the best way to solve my issue.

Since I have completely no knowledge on JavaFX, can anyone please provide me some hint?

Below is the Application.java as given from the project

```java
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static final String UI_FILE = "/ui.fxml";
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(UI_FILE));
        VBox root = (VBox) loader.load();
        Scene scene =  new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Team T-03: Course Scraper");
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

The Controller.java that I should implement the related loops and methods

```java
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private ProgressBar progressbar;

    @FXML
    void doSomething() {
        for (String object : objectList) {
            List<someObject> v = someOtherFunc(object);
            totalObjectCount += v.size();
            progress = (double) ++objectCount / v.size();
            progressbar.setProgress(progress);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _Since I have completely no knowledge on JavaFX_ then go ahead and learn it, the usual was is by working through tutorials ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`Task`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html),
and run it in a new `Thread`. A `Task` has its own progress property, and an `updateProgress` method that ensures the change to the progress is executed on the FX Application Thread. You can then bind your progress bar's progress to the task's:

```java
    @FXML
    void doSomething() {
        Task<Void> task = new Task<>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() {
                for (String object : objectList) {
                    List<someObject> v = someOtherFunc(object);
                    totalObjectCount += v.size();
                    updateProgress(++objectCount, objectList.size());
                }
                return null ;
            }
        }
        progressBar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
        new Thread(task).start();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks James! This code works! But is it normal for me to see the progress bar having flicks from left to right (like it is loading), when I start up the UI?

Comment: @edwardlam0328 I think that's because your calculation of the progress is wrong.

Comment: No I mean for when the program has not called the doSomething method yet. The bar behaves like the booting screen in Windows XP.

Comment: @edwardlam0328 Oh, yes; the progress bar is initially in an "undetermined" progress state. Just initialize it with `progress=0` if you want it to start empty. See [docs](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ProgressBar.html)